# selection с двумя условиями

Tags: sqlite, java

Можно ли в запросе query выбрать по двойному условию, типа - "login = ? AND password = ?" и как правильно при этом передать selectionArgs?   Конструкция вида String[][] не работает.

```
db.query("users", null, "login = ?", new String[] {login.toString()}, null, null, "last_visit DESC", "1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.query("users", null, "login = ? and password = ?", new String[] {login.toString(), password.toString()}, null, null, "last_visit DESC", "1")).moveToFirst());
```

Comment: опередили )